# Recovering from an invalid session id in the most elegant manner

Tags: php, regex, session, cookies, sessionid

Lately, I've been getting the following error(s) in my log:

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in [...] on line [..]
PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0
```

The answers to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are) suffice for *detecting* and *diverting* such scenarios, so that no error is generated, but I'm interested in the most elegant *recovery*; that is, ending up with a valid new (empty) session.

First, though, a few refinements to the detection & diversion code in that previous question, which is now six years old:

1. These days, sessions are more likely to be handled exclusively through cookies. The `session.use_only_cookies` flag in my php.ini is enabled, and since I don't remember changing it I assume this is the default value.
2. Which characters are used in a valid session id, and how many of those characters, depends on the `session.hash_function` and `session.hash_bits_per_character` values in php.ini. My values are 0 and 5, respectively, which (unless I'm mistaken) means my own session ids should match the regular expression `/^[a-v0-9]{26}$/`. I assume these are default values as well.
3. The name of the cookie used to store the session can be customized using `session.name` in php.ini. The correct value can always be retrieved using the `session_name()` function.

Given these, the most elegant means of diversion would (probably) be as follows:

```
function my_session_start() {
  if (!isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) || preg_match('/^[a-v0-9]{26}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()]) !== 0) {
    return session_start(); // since 5.3, returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure.
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

As for recovery (which would replace the `return false;` in the `else` block), [one answer to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24241252/3453461) suggested the following:

```
session_id(uniqid());
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

I'm concerned, however, that this means of recovery, having received only two upvotes and no comments, is insufficiently reviewed.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549632/handle-invalid-session-id) suggests that the internal `session_start()` function relies *directly* on the value of `$_COOKIE[session_name()]`, rather than some other internal representation of that value. Is this the case? If so, a `my_session_start()` function with detection and recovery could be as simple as:

```
function my_session_start() {
  if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && preg_match('/^[a-v0-9]{26}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()]) === 0) {
    unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);
  }

  return session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've only seen this happen when `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] === ''`. This happens when someone uses Firebug to "clear cookie". I want to only handle this specific scenario; if the session ID is invalid in some other way, I want to be warned. Dealing with my specific use case is simple:

```
$session_name = session_name();
if (isset($_COOKIE[$session_name]) and empty($_COOKIE[$session_name])) {
    // This happens when someone does "clear cookie" in Firebug; it causes session_start()
    // to trigger a warning. session_start() relies on $_COOKIE[$session_name], thus:
    unset($_COOKIE[$session_name]);
}
session_start();
```

Out of curiosity, do you actually need to deal with any scenario other than it being an empty string? It could only be something else if done maliciously (in order to trigger a warning), but since you have `display_errors` disabled in production, nobody can gain any information from that.